# How to deploy a flask application on Azure?

Tags: python, azure, flask

I am working on a Flask application and I need to deploy it on Azure.
I am totally new to Azure and I have built a project using Python Flask and HTML. In the application, I have one main Flask app and two HTML pages. I need to deploy the whole project to an Azure app service.
Can anyone please let me know how to do it on Windows?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend using VS Code and following a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-01). Note, Python is only supported on the Linux Azure App Services, not the Windows App Service (doesn't mean you can't develop on Windows, just your prod should be Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PGHE said, at present, **Python is supported on Azure App Service for Linux**.

You can refer to this article about [Deploy Python apps to Azure App Service on Linux from Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-01).

If you still want to publish python application to azure webapp on windows you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/publish-to-app-service-windows?view=vs-2019) while **the features about publishing to Azure App Service on Windows are deprecated** but continue to work.

Comment: thank you PGHE and Joey, on your valuable replies, I am using Pycharm to deploy my project. Is it possible from there ? and as the project contains both flask app and HTML pages so, do I need to use docker image to contain the project and deploy ?

Comment: If you flask app depend on html pages, when publish, the html will deploy together. You can also use docker image to container flask and html.

Comment: If it helps you, please accept it as answer. Thanks.